how to warping inside an itemize environment in latex
I want to warp a tickzpicture in the inside of an itemize environment, I write my document as follow:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools,mathrsfs,polynom,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,cases,graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\textLR{\arabic{equation}}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textLR{(\arabic{footnote})}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\makeatother
\fancypagestyle{first}{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\rfoot{يتبع ...}
\cfoot{\Large\textbf{ص: \textLR{\pageref{LastPage}$\setminus$\thepage}}}
\lfoot{}}
\fancypagestyle{second}{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\rfoot{إنتهى}
\cfoot{\Large\textbf{ص: \textLR{\pageref{LastPage}$\setminus$\thepage}}}
\lfoot{}}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{center}
{\Large\textbf{جامعة باتنة \textLR{1} - الحاج لخضر}}

\textbf{كلية العلوم الإقتصادية والتجارية وعلوم التسيير}

\textbf{قسم التعليم الأساسي}    
\end{center}
\textbf{المستوى:} \textLR{1} جذع مشترك
\hfill
\textbf{المادة:} رياضيات \textLR{1}
\hfill
\textbf{السداسي:} \textLR{1}
\hfill
\textbf{السنة الجامعية:} \textLR{2025$\setminus$2024}
\vspace{1 mm}
\hrule
\vspace{1 mm}
\centering
{\large\textbf{الإجابة النموذجية لإمتحان الدورة العادية أو الإستدراكية}}
\vspace{1 mm}
\hrule
\vspace{1 mm}
\thispagestyle{first}
\leqnomode
\begin{enumerate}[label={\large\textbf{ت \textLR{\arabic*}:}},leftmargin=*,align=left]
\item\textLR{\textcolor{red}{\large\textAR{(\textLR{8} نقاط)}}} % :ت 1

لدينا:
$$\begin{cases}
    U_0=1\\
    U_{n+1}=5U_n-1&n\in\mathbb{N}
  \end{cases}$$
\begin{enumerate}[label={\textLR{\arabic*}.},leftmargin=*,align=left]
\item % .1
حساب الحد
$U_1$:
$$U_1=5U_0-1=5\cdot 1-1=5-1\Longrightarrow\boxed{U_1=4}\quad\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}$$
حساب الحد
$U_2$:
$$U_2=5U_1-1=5\cdot 4-1=20-1\Longrightarrow\boxed{U_2=19}\quad\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}$$
حساب الحد
$U_3$:
$$U_3=5U_2-1=5\cdot 19-1=95-1\Longrightarrow\boxed{U_3=94}\quad\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}$$
\item % .2
لنتحقق أنه من أجل كل عدد طبيعي
$n$
لدينا
$U_n>\dfrac{1}{4}$
باستعمال الإستدلال بالتراجع:

نضع:
$P\left(n\right)\Longleftrightarrow U_n>\dfrac{1}{4}$

الشرط الإبتدائي:
$P\left(0\right)$؟
$$\begin{rcases}
   U_0=1\\
   1>\dfrac{1}{4}
  \end{rcases}\Longrightarrow U_0>\dfrac{1}{4}$$
إذن الشرط الإبتدائي
$P\left(0\right)$
محقق
\quad\textLR{\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{\textAR{ن} 0,5}}}

$P\left(n\right)\Longrightarrow P\left(n+1\right)$؟
\begin{align*}
P\left(n\right)\Longrightarrow &U_n>\dfrac{1}{4}\\
               \Longrightarrow &5U_n>\dfrac{5}{4}\quad\text{\textAR{(بضرب طرفي المتراجحة في $5$)}}\\
               \Longrightarrow &5U_n-1>\dfrac{5}{4}-1=\dfrac{5-4}{4}\quad\text{\textAR{(بطرح العدد $1$ من طرفي المتراجحة)}}\\
               \Longrightarrow &U_{n+1}>\dfrac{1}{4}\\
               \Longrightarrow &P\left(n+1\right)\quad\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{1}}}
\end{align*}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,align=left]
\item % *
استنتاج أن المتتالية
$\left(U_n\right)$
متزايدة تماما:
$$U_{n+1}-U_n=5U_n-1-U_n=4U_n-1=4\left(U_n-\dfrac{1}{4}\right)>0\quad\text{ \textAR{حسب ما سبق} $U_n>\dfrac{1}{4}$ \textAR{لأن}}$$
إذن المتتالية
$\left(U_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
متزايدة تماما
\quad\textLR{\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{\textAR{ن} 0,5}}}
\end{itemize}
\item % .3
لدينا:
$V_n=4U_n-1$
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,align=left]
\item % *
لنبين أن المتتالية
$\left(V_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
هي متتالية هندسية يطلب تعيين أساسها:
$$V_{n+1}=4U_{n+1}-1=4\left(5U_n-1\right)-1=20U_n-4-1=20U_n-5=5\left(4U_n-1\right)=5V_n$$
إذن
$\left(V_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
متتالية هندسية أساسها
$\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{1}}}\quad q=5$
تعيين حدها الأول:
$$V_0=4U_0-1=4\cdot 1-1=4-1\Longrightarrow\boxed{V_0=3}\quad\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}$$
\item % *
كتابة عبارة الحد العام للمتتالية
$\left(V_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$:
$$V_n=V_0\cdot q^n=1\cdot 5^n\Longrightarrow\boxed{V_n=5^n}\quad\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{1}}}$$
استنتاج عبارة الحد العام للمتتالية
$\left(U_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$:
$$V_n=4U_n-1\Longrightarrow 4U_n=V_n+1\Longrightarrow U_n=\dfrac{V_n+1}{4}\Longrightarrow\boxed{U_n=\dfrac{5^n+1}{4}}\quad\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{1}}}$$
\item % *
حساب المجموع
$S_n$
بدلالة
$n$:
\begin{align*}
S_n=&U_0+U_1+\cdots +U_n\\
   =&\dfrac{V_0+1}{4}+\dfrac{V_1+1}{4}+\cdots +\dfrac{V_n+1}{4}\\
   =&\dfrac{1}{4}\left(V_0+V_1+\cdots +V_n+n+1\right)\\
   =&\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot V_0\cdot\dfrac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}+\dfrac{1}{4}\left(n+1\right)\\
   =&\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot\dfrac{5^{n+1}-1}{5-1}+\dfrac{1}{4}n+\dfrac{1}{4}\\
   =&\dfrac{1}{16}\cdot 5^{n+1}-\dfrac{1}{16}+\dfrac{1}{4}n+\dfrac{1}{4}\\
   =&\dfrac{5^{n+1}}{16}+\dfrac{1}{4}n+\dfrac{3}{16}
\end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\thispagestyle{first}
\item\textLR{\textcolor{red}{\large\textAR{(\textLR{8} نقاط)}}} % :ت 2

لدينا:
$$f\left(x\right)=\left(x^2-5x+7\right)\mathrm{e}^x$$
\begin{enumerate}[label={\textLR{\arabic*}.},leftmargin=*,align=left]
\item % .1
لنتحقق أن الدالة
$f$
تقبل قيمتين حرجتين يطلب تعيينهما:
\begin{align*}
f^{\prime}\left(x\right)=&\left(2x-5\right)\mathrm{e}^x+\left(x^2-5x+7\right)\mathrm{e}^x\\
                        =&\left(2x-5+x^2-5x+7\right)\mathrm{e}^x\\
                        =&\left(x^2-3x+2\right)\mathrm{e}^x\quad\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{1}}}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
f^{\prime}\left(x\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow &\left(x^2-3x+2\right)\mathrm{e}^x=0\\
                          \Longleftrightarrow &x^2-3x+2=0
\end{align*}
$$\Delta=\left(-3\right)^2-4\left(1\right)\left(2\right)=9-8=1\Longleftrightarrow\sqrt{\Delta}=1$$
$$\begin{cases}
   x_1=\dfrac{3-1}{2}=1&\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}\\
   x_2=\dfrac{3+1}{2}=2&\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}
  \end{cases}$$
إذن الدالة
$f$
تقبل قيمتين حرجتين هما
$1$
و$2$.

تحديد نوعي القيمتين الحرجتين:
\begin{align*}
f^{\prime\prime}\left(x\right)=&\left(2x-3\right)\mathrm{e}^x+\left(x^2-3x+2\right)\mathrm{e}^x\\
                              =&\left(2x-3+x^2-3x+2\right)\mathrm{e}^x\\
                              =&\left(x^2-x-1\right)\mathrm{e}^x\quad\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{1}}}
\end{align*}
$$\begin{cases}
   f^{\prime\prime}\left(1\right)=\left(\cancel{1^2}-\cancel{1}-1\right)\mathrm{e}^1=-\mathrm{e}<0\Longrightarrow\text{ \textAR{الدالة $f$ تقبل نهاية حدية عظمى عند $1$}}&\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}\\
   f^{\prime\prime}\left(2\right)=\left(2^2-2-1\right)\mathrm{e}^2=\mathrm{e}^2>0\Longrightarrow\text{ \textAR{الدالة $f$ تقبل نهاية حدية صغرى عند $2$}}&\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}
  \end{cases}$$
\thispagestyle{first}
\item % .2
تعيين الدوال الأصلية للدالة
$x\longmapsto x^2\mathrm{e}^x$
باستعمال المكاملة بالتجزئة مرتين:

بوضع:
$\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}\quad
\begin{cases}
  u_1^{\prime}\left(x\right)=\mathrm{e}^{x}\\
  v_1\left(x\right)=x^2
 \end{cases}$
\qquad نجد:
$\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}\quad
\begin{cases}
  u_1\left(x\right)=\mathrm{e}^{x}\\
  v_1^{\prime}\left(x\right)=2x
 \end{cases}$

يصبح لدينا:
\begin{align*}
\int x^2\mathrm{e}^x\,\mathrm{d}x=&\int u_1^{\prime}\left(x\right)v_1\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
                                 =&u_1\left(x\right)v_1\left(x\right)-\int u_1\left(x\right)v_1^{\prime}\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
                                 =&x^2\mathrm{e}^x-2\int x\mathrm{e}^x\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
بوضع:
$\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}\quad
\begin{cases}
  u_2^{\prime}\left(x\right)=\mathrm{e}^{x}\\
  v_2\left(x\right)=x
 \end{cases}$
\qquad نجد:
$\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\textcolor{red}{ن \textLR{0,5}}}\quad
\begin{cases}
  u_2\left(x\right)=\mathrm{e}^{x}\\
  v_2^{\prime}\left(x\right)=1
 \end{cases}$

يصبح لدينا:
\begin{align*}
\int x^2\mathrm{e}^x\,\mathrm{d}x=&x^2\mathrm{e}^x-2\left(\int u_2^{\prime}\left(x\right)v_2\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
                                 =&x^2\mathrm{e}^x-2\left(u_2\left(x\right)v_2\left(x\right)-\int u_2\left(x\right)v_2^{\prime}\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
                                 =&x^2\mathrm{e}^x-2x\mathrm{e}^x+2\int\mathrm{e}^x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
                                 =&x^2\mathrm{e}^x-2x\mathrm{e}^x+2\mathrm{e}^x+c\\
                                 =&\left(x^2-2x+2\right)\mathrm{e}^x+c
\end{align*}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,align=left]
\item % *
استنتاج مساحة الحيز المستوي المحدد بين المنحنيين
$\left(\mathscr{C}_f\right)$
و$\left(\mathscr{C}_g\right)$
والمستقيم ذي المعادلة
$x=1$
كما هو مبين في الشكل التالي:

من الشكل نلاحظ أن
$\left(\mathscr{C}_f\right)$
و$\left(\mathscr{C}_g\right)$
يتقاطعان في النقطة ذات الإحداثيات
$\left(0,7\right)$
كما أن الوضع النسبي للمنحني
$\left(\mathscr{C}_f\right)$
تحت
$\left(\mathscr{C}_g\right)$
في المجال
$\left]0,1\right[$
وعليه:

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=0.5cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-0.75,
xmax=1.75,
ymin=-1.5,
ymax=9.5,
xtick={0,1},
ytick={-1,0,...,9},]
\clip(-0.75,-1.5) rectangle (1.75,9.5);
\draw[line width=0.8pt,color=green,fill=green,fill opacity=0.2] {[smooth,samples=50,domain=0:1] plot(\x,{((\x)^(2)-5*(\x)+7)*exp(\x)})} -- (1,{2*exp(1)}) {[smooth,samples=50,domain=1:0] -- plot(\x,{(-5*(\x)+7)*exp(\x)})} -- (0,7) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=1pt,color=blue,smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.75:1.75] plot(\x,{(\x^2-5*\x+7)*exp(\x)});
\draw[line width=1pt,color=red,smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.75:1.75] plot(\x,{(-5*\x+7)*exp(\x)});
\draw [->,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [->,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=blue] (0.5,8.5) node {$\left(\mathscr{C}_f\right)$};
\draw[color=red] (0.5,5.5) node {$\left(\mathscr{C}_g\right)$};
\draw[color=black] (-0.25,-0.5) node {$O$};
\draw[color=black] (0.5,-0.5) node {$\vec{i}$};
\draw[color=black] (-0.5,0.5) node {$\vec{j}$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\thispagestyle{second}
\end{document}

but I got this message:

Package wrapfig Warning: wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment on input line 276.



the compilation of that document gives the following PDF file


Welcome to TeX SE. Sadly, wrapfig and itemize are incompatible. See this post
